# VB Check if int is empty

Tags: vb.net, integer, value-type

A really boring question, sorry, but I really don't know that yet ;) I've tried always string.empty, but with a decimal this produces an error.

Is there any function? Unfortunately, for the simplest questions, there are no answers on google

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your title (and tag) asks about an "int", but your question says that you're getting an error with a "decimal". Either way, **there is no such thing as "empty" when it comes to a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)** (such as an `Integer`, `Decimal`, etc.). They cannot be set to `Nothing` as you could with a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) (like a `String` or class). Instead, **value types have an implicit default constructor that automatically initializes your variables of that type to its default value.** For numeric values like `Integer` and `Decimal`, this is 0. For other types, see [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

So you can check to see if a value type has been initialized with the following code:

```
Dim myFavoriteNumber as Integer = 24
If myFavoriteNumber = 0 Then
    ''#This code will obviously never run, because the value was set to 24
End If

Dim mySecondFavoriteNumber as Integer
If mySecondFavoriteNumber = 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("You haven't specified a second favorite number!")
End If
```

Note that `mySecondFavoriteNumber` is automatically initialized to 0 (the default value for an `Integer`) behind the scenes by the compiler, so the `If` statement is `True`. In fact, the declaration of `mySecondFavoriteNumber` above is equivalent to the following statement:

```
Dim mySecondFavoriteNumber as Integer = 0
```

Of course, as you've probably noticed, there's no way to know whether a person's favorite number is *actually* 0, or if they just haven't specified a favorite number yet. **If you truly need a value type that can be set to `Nothing`, you could use [`Nullable(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)**, declaring the variable instead as:

```
Dim mySecondFavoriteNumber as Nullable(Of Integer)
```

And checking to see if it has been assigned as follows:

```
If mySecondFavoriteNumber.HasValue Then
    ''#A value has been specified, so display it in a message box
    MessageBox.Show("Your favorite number is: " & mySecondFavoriteNumber.Value)
Else
    ''#No value has been specified, so the Value property is empty
    MessageBox.Show("You haven't specified a second favorite number!")
End If
```

Comment: Just a side note: actually you *can* assign Nothing to a value type in VB.Net. But in that case, Nothing does not mean 'null' but 'default(T)', so for integers it's the same as 0.

Comment: @jeroenh: That's correct. Notice that I said they can't be set to `Nothing` *as you could with a reference type*. Setting a value type to `Nothing` will cause it to be initialized back to its default type. The point is that there is no such `null` or "empty" state for value types; they always contain a value.

Comment: Note more recently, `Dim mySecondFavoriteNumber as Integer?` is the same as `Dim mySecondFavoriteNumber as Nullable(Of Integer)`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what you are looking for is Nullable

```
    Dim foo As Nullable(Of Integer) = 1
    Dim bar As Nullable(Of Decimal) = 2

    If foo = 1 Then
        If bar = 2 Then
            foo = Nothing
            bar = Nothing
            If foo Is Nothing AndAlso bar Is Nothing Then Stop
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the default value for a number would be 0, but you can also try this:

```
int x = 123;
String s = "" + x;
```

and then check the length or if the string 's' is empty.

Comment: This method doesn't work in .Net 4.5.2... The length of an uninitialized integer is 1 and you need to convert to a string with ToString. I think this answer might've been in C :)